# Winter Bash を有効にしている場合に投稿日時の表示が崩れる

Tags: バグ, 延期, デザイン, winter-bash

### 不具合事象

帽子が大好きなユーザのみ、投稿日時の表示が崩れます。また、これは帽子が嫌いなユーザには発生しません。

---

### スクリーンショット

以下は 「[Python 3 で、文字列と整数が混在するリストから負数をint型で取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38998/python-3-%E3%81%A7-%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%A8%E6%95%B4%E6%95%B0%E3%81%8C%E6%B7%B7%E5%9C%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E8%B2%A0%E6%95%B0%E3%82%92int%E5%9E%8B%E3%81%A7%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/39000#39000)」で再現した問題のスクリーンショットです。

#### 回答日時

**帽子好きの場合**
[image: 帽子好きの場合は回答日時がずれている]

**帽子嫌いの場合**
[image: 帽子嫌いの場合は回答日時がずれていない]

#### 更新日時

**帽子好きの場合**
[image: 帽子好きの場合は更新日時がずれている]

**帽子嫌いの場合**
[image: 帽子嫌いの場合は更新日時がずれていない]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常のアイコン画像の表示領域を"オーバーフロー"して配置できることが直接の原因ですが、Winter-Bash自体が期間限定の機能であることと、本当に気になるようであればユーザー自身が個別にオフにすることもできるので、対応の優先度は下がると思います。

なお、MSEでの関連質問では「デザインによる仕様」という見解のようです。
(ちょうど "Stack **Overflow**" というサイトの名前と同じだ、とも)

[Hats can overflow, covering links in review queue - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288355)